# Loop blog post filtered by a category on SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm working on a SilverStripe site and have installed the [blog module](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/blog).

I have my blog set up with multiple categories such as *News*, *Events*, *Announcements*, *Photo Galleries*, etc.

The problem I run into is that I want to showcase the latest blog post (title, image, some of the content) of each category on my front page.

I can easily loop the blog post using this solution:  http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/blog-module-forum/show/102585?start=8

**/mysite/code/Page.php**

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    public function latestBlog($num = 3) {
        return BlogPost::get()
                ->sort('PublishDate', 'desc')
                ->limit($num);
    }
}
```

**/themes/simple/templates/Page.ss**

```
<ol>
<% loop $latestBlog %>
    <li>$Title</li>
    <p>$Content</p>
<% end_loop %>
</ol>
```

But I can't figure out how to loop while filtering by a category. For example something like this logic:

```
return BlogPost::get()
        ->FILTER('Category', 'News')
        ->sort('PublishDate', 'desc')
        ->limit($num);
```

The idea is to loop *News* and code it a certain way so it looks different on the  front page, then loop *Photo Galleries*.

I can't find anything that works on how to do this.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `relation` method on `DataList`: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-DataList.html#_relation

```
return BlogCategory::get()
    ->filter('Title', 'News')
    ->relation('BlogPosts')
    ->sort('PublishDate', 'DESC')
    ->limit($num);
```

This will return a list of blog posts filtered by the defined category (news).

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot